# Class-wide exception handler

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I would like to implement a way to globally handle exceptions in a class coming through my application rather than handle them at the call site because it will cause a lot of duplicate code.

For example's sake say I have a class like so:

```
class handler():
    def throws_value_error(self):
        raise ValueError

    def throws_not_implemented_error(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    # ... Imagine there are hundreds of these
```

In this handler class I'd like all `ValueError` and `NotImplementedError` handled the same way - a message saying `[ERROR]: ...` where `...` is the details from the particular instance.

Instead of reproducing a TON of:

```
try:
    #...
except Exception as e:
    # Catch the instances of the exception and handle them
    # in more-or-less the same way here
```

I'd like to have a single method implementable on the class that takes care of this in general:

```
def exception_watcher(self):
    # Big if...elif...else for handling these types of exceptions
```

Then, this method would be invoked when any `Exception` inside the class is given.

My motivation is to use this to implement a generic sort of controller interface where a controller method could throw a subclass of an exception (for example - `BadRequestException` which is subclassed from `Error400Exception`). From there, the handler could dispatch a method to properly configure a response with an error code tailored to the type of exception, and additionally return a useful reply to the consumer.

Obviously this is doable without this dispatcher - but this way certainly saves a ton of duplicated code (and therefore bugs).

I've done a lot of digging around the internet and I haven't found anything. Admittedly I am borrowing this pattern from the Spring Boot Framework. I will also accept this being non-pythonic as an answer (as long as you can tell me how to do it right!)

Any help would be appreciated - thank you!

Comment: Hi! What if your exception conditions will change? 
"In this handler class I'd like all ValueError and NotImplementedError handled the same way" What if some day you'll want to threat those errors differently? This can cause problems, if you'll have lots code based on this logic.

Comment: @Tino in this case I would think a modification to a singular handler would make changing the logic around these cases simpler - especially since the logic is based around a subclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifying functions without altering their core functionality is exactly what decorators are for. Take a look at this example and try running it:

```
def catch_exception(func):
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        except ValueError:
            self.value_error_handler()
        except NotImplementedError:
            self.ni_error_handler()
    return wrapped

class Handler:
    def value_error_handler(self):
        print("found value error")

    def ni_error_handler(self):
        print("found not implemented error")

    @catch_exception
    def value_error_raiser(self):
        raise ValueError

    @catch_exception
    def ni_error_raiser(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

h = Handler()
h.value_error_raiser()
h.ni_error_raiser()
```

Because of the `@catch_exception` decorator, the decorated methods do not raise the errors shown when caled; instead, they call the respective method defined inside `wrapped`'s try/except block, printing a message.

While this is not exactly what you asked for, I believe this solution is more manageable overall. You can both choose exactly what methods should raise exceptions regularly and which should be handled by `catch_exception` (by deciding which methods are decorated), and add future behaviour for other exception types by writing an extra `except` block inside `wrapped` and adding the respective method to the `Handler` class.

Note that this is not a "clean" solution, since `wrapped` expects to know that `self` is an instance of `Handler`, seeing as it calls a bunch of its methods, even though it is a function outside the `Handler` class... But hey, that's Python's duck typing for you :-P